# Why is my TransformFromPoint returning false values?

Tags: unity

I have been using transformFromPoint a lot of time in my game.

Though recently I stuck at the following:

```
target.TransformFromPoint(target.localPosition)
```

The output should give me `(-5,0,0)` but its giving me `(-10,0,0)`

What may be the cause? I have removed everything from the script and debug the script via VS, but the same thing is occurring.

The script is on camera which is supposed to follow the player.

Here is the code,

```
public Transform target;
Vector3 tempTarget;
void LateUpdate()
{
  tempTarget = target.TransformPoint(target.localPosition);
  Debug.Log("pos " + tempTarget);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code? We can't really help you right now because you've given so little information.

Comment: there is only target.TransformFromPoint(target.localPosition) in script whereas target is player object...

Comment: You are using `(-5,0,0)` and `(-10,0,0)`. Where do these numbers come from? What are you transforming? What is the initial position before the transformation?

Comment: public Transform target;
Vector3 tempTarget;
void LateUpdate()
    {
  tempTarget = target.TransformPoint(target.localPosition);
  Debug.Log("pos " + tempTarget);

}

That should give me (-5,0,0) as my target player is on that axis,though the output I am getting is (-10,0,0)

Comment: Then please edit your question to include this code snippet as well as all relevant information, like the starting position of the player, what is the applied transformation, etc.

Comment: ok I guess I solved it myself by adding ,  tempTarget.x = target.localPosition.x;

Comment: If you answered your own question, feel free to create an answer with the solution and accept it after the 2 days delay.

Comment: nah that didnt worked....if player moves horizontally then problem arises again

Comment: wow, I found the solution,tempTarget = target.parent.TransformPoint(target.localPosition);

the problem seems to be that we cannot get world ordinates of child via child,we have to get it from parent...surprisingly this is the first time this occurred...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25411/discussion-between-alexandre-desbiens-and-idurvesh).